# Create a model that switches between two different states using Temporal Logic?

Tags: python, logic, discrete-mathematics, continuous, temporal

Im trying to design a model that can manage different requests for different water sources.
Platform : MAC OSX, using latest Python with TuLip module installed.

For example,

```
Definitions :

Two water sources : w1 and w2
3 different requests : r1,r2,and r3
```

-

```
Specifications :

Water 1 (w1) is preferred, but w2 will be used if w1 unavailable.
Water 2 is only used if w1 is depleted.
r1 has the maximum priority.
If all entities request simultaneously, r1's supply must not fall below 50%.
```

-

The water sources are not discrete but rather continuous, this will increase the difficulty of creating the model. I can do a crude discretization for the water levels but I prefer finding a model for the continuous state first.

So how do I start doing that ?

Some of my thoughts :

- Create a matrix W where w1,w2 ∈ W
- Create a matrix R where r1,r2,r3 ∈ R
- or leave all variables singular without putting them in a matrix

I'm not an expert in coding so that's why I need help. Not sure what is the best way to start tackling this problem.
I am only interested in the model, or a code sample of how can this be put together.

*edit*

Now imagine I do a crude discretization of the water sources to have w1=[0...4] and w2=[0...4] for 0, 25, 50, 75,100 percent respectively.

==> means *implies*

Usage of water sources  :

- if w1[0]==>w2[4] -- meaning if water source 1 has 0%, then use 100% of water source 2 etc
- if w1[1]==>w2[3]
- if w1[2]==>w2[2]
- if w1[3]==>w2[1]
- if w1[4]==>w2[0]

r1=r2=r3=[0,1] -- 0 means request *OFF* and 1 means request *ON*

Now what model can be designed that will give each request 100% water depending on the values of w1 and w2 (w1 and w2 values are uncontrollable so cannot define specific value, but 0...4 is used for simplicity )

Comment: Just a thought - this is not my area of specialism - would you be able to utilise an event loop system? Perhaps so that when w1 is depleted, an event is emitted, which can be caught and used to switch to w2?

Comment: @CallumMcLean Hmm can you please elaborate ?

Comment: On what? What an event loop is or how it would be used?

Comment: @CallumMcLean The usage of the event loop in this situation

Comment: Event loops to one side for a moment, when a request is received, why not just check the levels of w1 and w2 to see which supply can match the request?

Comment: I can do that, however I want to avoid a crude discretization of w1 and w2. So knowing actual levels is not straightforward since they're continuous. @CallumMcLean

Comment: So you want to be able to choose between sources based on their levels, but without knowing what their levels are?

Comment: @CallumMcLean Okay I got a better explanation. Im editing my question now

Comment: If this is a continuous calculation, why don't you just model this with continuous equations, and analyse the functions to achieve whatever you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

This is called the flow problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem

Wiki has some code for the solution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm

I'm not sure temporal logic is of much help here. For example load balancing is a major research topic, and I believe most of it doesn't use this formalism.

I have coded something, which only represents a simple priority list, which is kind of trivial. I would use classes and functions to represent states, not matrices. The dependencies in terms of priority are simple enough. Otherwise you can add those to the class watersource aswell. (class WaterSourcePriorityQueue or something like that). To get a simulation it is good to use threads, which I haven't here. You can use stepwise iteration (rounds), which is more in line with a procedural program.

```
import time
from random import random
from math import floor
import operator

class Watersource:

    def __init__(self,initlevel,prio,name):
        self.level = initlevel
        self.priority = prio
        self.name = name

    def requestWater(self,amount):
        if amount < self.level:
            self.level -= amount
            return True
        else:
            return False


#watersources
w1 = Watersource(40,1,"A")
w2 = Watersource(30,2,"B")
w3 = Watersource(20,3,"C")

probA = 0.8 # probability A will be requested
probB = 0.7
probC = 0.9

probs = {w1:probA,w2:probB,w3:probC}
amounts = {w1:10,w2:10,w3:20} # amounts requested

ws = [w1,w2,w3]

numrounds = 100
for round in range(1,numrounds):
    print 'round ',round

    done = False
    i = 0
    priorRequest = False
    prioramount = 0

    while not done or priorRequest:
        if i==len(ws):
            done=True
            break

        w = ws[i]
        probtresh = probs[w]
        prob = random()

        if prob > probtresh: # request water
            if prioramount != 0:
                amount = prioramount
            else:
                amount = floor(random()*amounts[w])
                prioramount = amount

            print 'requesting ',amount

            success = w.requestWater(amount)

            if not success:
                print 'not enough'

                priorRequest=True
            else:
                print 'got water'
                done = True
                priorRequest=False

        i+=1



    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Great reply, I like what you have done here. This can be implemented in Linear Temporal Logic too. However, I need to figure out how to signal the water supply that a component needs water.